# Generator for n-records of a real time stream

Tags: python, concurrency, stream, generator

I subscribe to a real time stream which publishes a small JSON record at a slow rate (0.5 KBs every 1-5 seconds). The publisher has provided a python client that exposes these records. I write these records to a list in memory. The client is just a python wrapper for doing a curl command on a HTTPS endpoint for a dataset. A dataset is defined by filters and fields. I can let the client go for a few days and stop it at midnight to process multiple days worth of data as one batch.

Instead of multi-day batches described above, I'd like to write every n-records by treating the stream as a generator. The client code is below. I just added the append() line to create a list called 'records' (in memory) to playback later:

```
records=[]
data_set = api.get_dataset(dataset_id='abc')
for record in data_set.request_realtime(): 
    records.append(record)
```

which as expected, gives me [*] in Jupyter Notebook; and keeps running.

Then, I created a generator from my list in memory as follows to extract one record (n=1 for initial testing):

```
def Generator():
    count = 1
    while count < 2:
            for r in records:
                yield r.data
            count +=1
```

But my generator definition also gave me [*] and kept calculating; which I understand it is because the list is still being written in memory. But I thought my generator would be able to lock the state of my list and yield the first n-records. But it didn't. How can I code my generator in this case? And if a generator is not a good choice in this use case, please advise.

To give you the full picture, if my code was working, then, I'd have instantiated it, printed it, and received an object as expected like this:

```
>>>my_generator = Generator()
>>>print(my_generator)
<generator object Gen at 0x0000000009910510>
```

Then, I'd have written it to a csv file like so:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    cf = csv.DictWriter(f, column_headers, extrasaction='ignore') 
    cf.writeheader()
    cf.writerows(i.data for i in my_generator)
```

Note: I know there are many tools for this e.g. Kafka; but I am in an initial PoC phase. Please use Python 2x. Once I get my code working, I plan on stacking generators to set up my next n-record extraction so that I don't lose data in between. Any guidance on stacking would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how concurrency works. Unless some magic is being used that you didn't tell us about, while your first code returns `*` you can't run more code. Putting the generator in another cell just adds it to a queue to run when the first code finishes - since the first code will never finish, the second code will never even start running!

I suggest looking into some asynchronous networking library, like `asyncio`, `twisted` or `trio`. They allow you to make functions cooperative so while one of them is waiting for data, the other can run, instead of blocking. You'd probably have to rewrite the `api.get_dataset` code to be asynchronous as well.